# MvvmCross vNext: Using System.IO.Compression in PCL

Tags: windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, portable-class-library, mvvmcross

I have some Model code that requires some methods from the System.IO.Compression namespace. However it is not present when using a PCL that targets VSMonoTouch and MonoAndroid as well. I see that some stuff is TypeForwarded in the MvvmCross solution, though when creating a similar project I can't seem to find out how to use it.

I created a MonoAndroid library project and added a Forward.cs class with the following content:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(System.IO.Compression.GZipStream))]
```

I have set the namespace of the project to `System.IO.Compression`. Trying to add it as a reference to the PCL project I have with my Model code which contains ViewModels, Services and what not it of course says that it can only reference other PCL projects and assemblies.

I especially need `GZipStream` and I cannot seem to find out how to add it to my project, so the question is how do I do that?

Comment: Did you end up implementing this?

Comment: Only have a local copy, but basically I am using the Plugin route Stuart describes below. So I simply inject the platform specific GZip code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### PCL Extension route

How to do this by extending PCL... I'm not entirely sure! One of the PCL guys might be able to assist with that.

---

#### Plugin route

The way I'd go about this is by defining the functionality I want in an interface and wrapping the code in a plugin.

For example in `Cheesebaron.Plugins.Gzip.dll` you could create an interface like:

```
public interface IGZipStreamFactory
{
     Stream Decompress(Stream binaryStream);
}
```

This interface would then get plugged inside a PCL library that just contained this interface and the pluginmanager class.

Your PCL Core project can then reference this PCL plugin library and your ViewModel can use code like:

```
 Cheesebaron.Plugins.GZip.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
```

followed by

```
 var service = this.GetService<IGZipStreamFactory>();
 var unzipped = service.Decompress(inputStream);
```

For each actual platform implementation, you then prepare a platform specific library, you implement the GZip factory interface, and you provide a simple `Plugin` class implementation.

For example, for Droid you might create `Cheesebaron.Plugins.Gzip.Droid.dll`:

```
 public class MyDroidGZipStreamFactory : IGZipStreamFactory
 {
      // the implementation
 }
```

And you'd then add:

```
public class Plugin
    : IMvxPlugin
    , IMvxServiceProducer
{
    public void Load()
    {
        this.RegisterServiceInstance<IGZipStreamFactory>(new MyDroidGZipStreamFactory));
    }
}
```

Finally... to pull it all together, for MonoDroid you then reference both the PCL and the platform specific implementation in your UI project - and it should all work!

**Note** that there is a little convention based magic going on behind the scenes here - the framework loads the Assembly `Cheesebaron.Plugins.Gzip.Droid.dll` based on the PCL Plugin namespace being `Cheesebaron.Plugins.Gzip`

(For WP7 and other platforms, there's one additional step - there's a setup method to override which registers the plugin)

---

**Note** you can register as many services as you want to inside a single PlugIn, and you can perform extra common initialization/setup code too. This can help to reduce some project maintenance overhead: you can put your CheeseBaron IoC objects inside one single `CheeseBaron.Plugins.Utils` project if you like and then share just this one plugin across all your apps.

The `DownloadCache` Plugin provides a small sample of this - it registers all of `IMvxHttpFileDownloader`, `IMvxImageCache` and `IMvxLocalFileImageLoader`.

The downside with doing this is: eventual linked exe size - you're potentially adding unneeded code to each app.

---

Obviously this plugin approach has a little bit of a learning curve... and it does add a little project maintenance - but the good news is that these plugins can be used over and over again between projects - and can be shared between organisations (at least, that's my hope!)

More on creating plugins at:

- [MvvmCross vnext: merge plugins with monodroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931618/mvvmcross-vnext-merge-plugins-with-monodroid)
- http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/mvvm-mvvmcross-monodroid-monotouch-wp7.html

For examples of plugins (not all available on all platforms), see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/vnext/Cirrious/Plugins

---

#### Other routes

If you don't want to use Plugins - e.g. if you are ever in a hurry or if you are writing code for a module that you don't want to reuse, then there are alternatives:

- You can define an interface like IGZipStreamFactory in your share Core PCL library. You can then provide a platform specific implementation of this interface within each UI project, and can then use normal IoC/DI in the ViewModel/Model/Service layer in order to locate the correct implementation at runtime.

Or...

- You can just dump the shared PCL core library and create separate platform-specific DLLs into which you then manually link in platform-specific files (I try never to do this, but others like it)

Comment: The Plugin way seems to be the best as it will allow me to reuse the functionality in other applications. I will have a look into that. Fortunately you have provided me with a lot of samples in the MvvmCross solution so I have something for reference. Thanks!

Comment: Cool :) Thanks for the qu. I've just added one update - just pointing out that Plugins are just DLLs - so you can put as many interfaces and as much code as you want into them - you don't have to just stick to 1 interface for each DLL :)

Comment: Would I need to do this to allow access to System.Threading classes too? It seems a bit stupid to have plugins for almost everything...

Comment: It depends which bit of System.Threading - e.g. for something as simple as Sleep I had to add a plugin - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/vnext/Cirrious/Plugins/ThreadUtils - I agree this is a shame. To counter the "plugins for almost everything" line, 1. It's nowhere near almost everything :) 2. You can always drop down to just UI-injected services for small cases. 3. At a practical level, to prevent you having too many dll's you can always write one big fat plugin providing lots of services.

Comment: The PCL team are aware that the PCL footprint is too small still - they are working on it - in the meantime, there are some really good ideas in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx - give them feedback and they will build...

Comment: Specifically for System.Threading, I've held off doing too much - the threading world is about to be revolutionised when async/await hits all the platforms.

Comment: Did anyone actually make this?